# CCS3 transform origin not correct when using px

Tags: css, transform

I have a square and its animation code up with pure html and css. Here is the jsbin url to the code: https://jsbin.com/medupun/edit?html,output

And following is the most relevant CSS part:

```
.foo {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100px 0%;
}

.foo:hover {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

The square is 100px by 100 px. I want its transform origin to be the 
top right corner of itself . I am seeking to do it with just x/y-offset. So I do it with "-webkit-transform-origin: 100px 0%;".

However, I see the square does not rotate around the top right corner, rather a point close to it. And what surprises me is, if I change the origin to 130px 0%, it will work.

Can someone help me understand where is the extra 30px comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have padding on your square that adds the `30px`.

```
  padding: 1em;
```

Remove that to get the results you are looking for.

```
 .foo {
      position: absolute;
      top: 400px;
      left: 400px;
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      background: #ffea61;
      -webkit-transition: all 750ms ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transform-origin: 100px 0;
    }

    .foo:hover {
      -webkit-transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
```

https://jsbin.com/zovucefuxi/edit?html,output

Comment: Thank you! That is the culprit.